# Installed iOS app is not reflecting new code changes

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm have made some minor changes to the code which are not getting reflected after the app is installed on iPhone5s(ios 9.3.1). I tried to clean the app and the build folder, but that also did not help.
What could be the reason that the app is not having the new code changes.
This app when ran on simulator, the changes are reflected properly.
Tried but could not find proper solution anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the derived data? `Window` -> `Projects`, navigate to your project and click on `Delete...` button next to your Derived Data directory

Comment: And remove the app from your device before installing new one.

Comment: Thanks noir_eagle, but this is also not working for me. Old content is getting loaded. I deleted the derived data and app as you said but still no updated code is reflected.

Answer (score 1):

- Before build and run the app, you should remove your app from device and check.

Comment: Guys, the problem got solved, for our project just created a new archive and that took the updated code.